# how search on a specific rows of a dataframe to find a match in a second dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set and I wanna do the following task in an efficient way. suppose we have 2 data frames. for each element in `df2` I wanna search in the first data set `df1`  only in row where the first 2 letters are in common then the word with the most common token is choosen.
Let's see in an example:

```
df1: 

common work   co
summer hot    su
apple         ap
colorful fall  co
support it     su
could comp     co

df2:

condition work it  co
common mistakes    co
could comp work    co
summer             su
```

Take the first row of `df2` as an example (`condition work it`). I wanna find a row in `df1` where they have the same `first_two` and have the most common token.

The `first_two` of `condition work it` is `co`. so I wanna search in `df1`  where `first_two` is `co`. So the search is done among: `common work`, `colorful fall`, `could comp` since `condition work it` has 1 common token with `common work` it is selected.

output:

```
df2:
name               first_two      match
condition work it  co              `common work`     
common mistakes    co              `common work`
could comp work    co              `could comp` 
summer             su              `summer hot'
appears            ap                  Nane
```

The last row is Nane since there is no common word between `appears` and `apple`

I did following:

```
df3=(df1.groupby(['first_two'])
      .agg({'name': lambda x: ",".join(x)})
      .reset_index())
merge_=df3.merge(df2, on='first_two',how='inner')
```

But now I have to search in `name_x` for each `name_y`. how to find an element of `name_x` whose has the most common token with `name_y`?

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty much explained the most efficient method already.

1. Extract first 2 letters using `.str.[:2]` for the series and assign it to new columns in both the dataframe.
2. Extract unique values of 2 letter column from df2.
3. Inner join the result from #2 on to df1.
4. Perform a group by count on the result of #3 and sort descending based on the count and drop duplicates to get the most repeated item for the 2 letter column.
5. Left join result of #4 onto df2.